# Template Specialization for each Range Type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

## Background

In C++11 the range-based for loop handles three kinds of "ranges," outlined [here (link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). I've quoted the relevant part below.

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> for (range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement
> ```
>
> ### Explanation
>
> The above syntax produces code similar to the following (`__range`, `__begin` and `__end` are for exposition only):
>
> ```
> {
>      auto && __range = range_expression;
>      for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
>          __end = end_expr;
>          __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
>          range_declaration = *__begin;
>          loop_statement
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> The `range_expression` is evaluated to determine the sequence or range will be iterated over. Each element of the sequence is dereferenced, and assigned to the variable using the type and name given in the `range_declaration`.
>
> The `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are defined to be either:
>
> - If `(__range)` is an array, then `(__range)` and `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the array bound;
> - If `(__range)` is a class and has either a begin or end member (or both), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`;
> - Otherwise, `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, which are found based on argument-dependent lookup rules with `std` as an associated namespace.

## Question

How should I write a template function with **three specializations that handle the exact same three cases** in the quoted bullet list?

I'm thinking something like the following, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

```
//Handle third bullet - default case
template <typename Range>
void f(Range& range)
{
    for (auto it = begin(range); it != end(range); ++it)
    {
        T& item = *it;
        /* do something custom with item */
    }
}

//Handle first bullet - "range" is an array
template <>
void f<T[]>(T[] range)
{
    auto end = range + sizeof(range)/sizeof(*range);
    for (auto it = range; it != end; ++it)
    {
        T& item = *it;
        /* do something custom with item */
    }
}

//Handle second bullet - "range" with "begin" and/or "end" function
template <>
void f<RangeBE>(RangeBE& range)
{
    //Somehow restrict type RangeBE to classes that have
    //begin or end member functions...
    //Can enable_if be used for this?

    for (auto it = range.begin(); it != range.end(); ++it)
    {
        T& item = *it;
        /* do something custom with item */
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this completely incorrectly? Is this even possible to do with C++11 (i.e., does the compiler get to do something special to accomplish this kind of specialization)? Please enlighten me. :)

## Some clarification...

My question is **how to handle all three** possible types of "range" (from the quoted bullet list) **as inputs to a function I write**. (I will be using the knowledge gained here to actually write a class qualified with `template <typename Range>` in the same way, where the class has specializations that handle all three types of ranges.)

My question is ***not*** how to write a class that satisfies one of the three possible types of "range" (from the quoted bullet list). There are multiple SO questions about that - this is not a duplicate of those.

My question is ***not*** how to use range-based for loops.

"Just use range-based for loops in `f`" is ***not*** an option or an answer. What I'm actually trying to do is mimic the semantics of range-based for loops, but because of complications outside the scope of this question, I can't simply use a range-based for loop inside of the example function `f`. **Please accept the fact that I have good reason to not "Just use a range-based for loop." It would be too complicated to explain why.**

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to "write a template function with three specializations that handle the exact same three cases in the quoted bullet list?"  It's super easy to make one function that handles all three cases...

Comment: @MooingDuck My reason for asking this question was motivated by my project: https://github.com/timothy-shields/linq-cpp If you want to iterate these different types of ranges in a pull-based enumerable fashion, you need to handle them all differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to mimic the semantics of a *range-based for loop* is to use a *range-based for loop*. But since your clarification makes that not an option, and we are left wondering what can you possibly intend to do, then there is another approach:

Use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) which already exhibit the semantics you expect, and are written in plain *C++11*. Remembering to enable *ADL* to kick in, to mimic the third bullet in the semantics on a *range-based for loop*, it ends up looking something like this:

```
template<typename Range>
void f(Range& range)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    for(auto it = begin(range), end_it = end(range); it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        T& item = *it;
        /* do something custom with item */
    }
}
```

If you wonder how `std::begin/end` work, then just look at their declarations:

```
template< class C >
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

This overload is a function template that has an expression in it to deduce its return type. Due to *SFINAE*, when said expression results in an error in the immediate context once replaced `C` with the actual type, it is simply discarded from the overload set (as if it didn't even existed)

```
template< class T, size_t N >
T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

This overload handles the array case. Note that your approach is incorrect, as you are dealing with an array of incomplete size, and there is no way you can get the number of elements in one of those.

Comment: So if I do `for (auto it = std::begin(range); it != std::end(range); ++it) { ... }` that will behave *identically* to a range-based for loop for all three types of ranges? I had seen `std::begin` and `std::end` in documentation, but I wasn't sure if they behaved that way.

Comment: Timothy Shields: No, you need to enable _ADL_ to get identical behavior.

Comment: Is "enable ADL" accomplished by the `using std::begin;` and `using std::end;` statements in combination with the *unqualified* `begin` and `end` calls?

Comment: Timothy Shields: "enabling ADL" is calling a function by using an unqualified id. Not an expression resulting in a function, but simply the unqualified name of a function. The `using` bit is used to establish a "default overload" that will be considered together with any other overload found in associated namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. :) This has helped me tremendously!

Comment: @TimothyShields: This isn't in fact 100% identical, since it allows a class defining `begin` as a member function and `end` as a free function, or viceversa, while a _range-based for loop_ would fail. If you do care about those ill-formed cases, there is extra work to be done...

Comment: If you could update your answer to include how to fix that last issue, i.e. addressing "If (__range) is a class and has either a begin or end member (or both), then begin_expr is __range.begin() and end_expr is __range.end();", that would be great. :)