# Get Iterator Type from Range Type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

*Related: [Template Specialization for each Range Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160339/template-specialization-for-each-range-type)*

## Background

In C++11 the range-based for loop handles three kinds of "ranges," outlined [here (link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). I've quoted the relevant part below.

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> for (range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement
> ```
>
> ### Explanation
>
> The above syntax produces code similar to the following (`__range`, `__begin` and `__end` are for exposition only):
>
> ```
> {
>      auto && __range = range_expression;
>      for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
>          __end = end_expr;
>          __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
>          range_declaration = *__begin;
>          loop_statement
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> The `range_expression` is evaluated to determine the sequence or range will be iterated over. Each element of the sequence is dereferenced, and assigned to the variable using the type and name given in the `range_declaration`.
>
> The `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are defined to be either:
>
> - If `(__range)` is an array, then `(__range)` and `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the array bound;
> - If `(__range)` is a class and has either a begin or end member (or both), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`;
> - Otherwise, `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, which are found based on argument-dependent lookup rules with `std` as an associated namespace.

## Question

How can I write something to get the type of the iterator the range-based for loop uses, given the type of `range_expression`? (Similar to how `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` gets me the type of iterator values given the type of `Iterator`.)

I want to be able to write `range_traits<Range>::iterator_type` given some range type `Range` and have that be the type of the iterator that a range-based for loop would use.

I tried this:

```
template <typename Range>
struct range_traits
{
    //Try to use ADL to get correct "begin" function, or std::begin by default
    using std::begin;
    typedef typename decltype(begin(std::declval<Range>())) iterator_type;
};
```

This doesn't work, however, because in the context of a using declaration in a class body, a `using` declaration is for declaring base class members.

The following *does* work, because the `using std::begin` does what I want it to (makes `std::begin` the default if ADL fails).

```
template <typename Range>
void example(Range& range)
{
    using std::begin;
    auto it = begin(range); //it is of the type I want
    //the expression decltype(begin(range)) would get the type I want
}
```

The problem is that I can't actually get the type "out of" the function body.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this task? Is there some SFINAE magic that can be used? If it's not clear what I'm trying to accomplish, I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9402618/390913

Comment: Is ranged for loop always using a forward/input iterator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get the "iterator" for a template type, regardless if that type is an array or STL-like container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402476/can-i-get-the-iterator-for-a-template-type-regardless-if-that-type-is-an-arra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to have worked ok:

```
#include <iterator>

namespace range_trait_namespace {
  using std::begin;
  template<typename Range>struct range_traits {
    typedef decltype(begin(std::declval<Range>())) iterator_type;
  };
}


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int, char**) {
  std::cout << "oi\n";
  std::vector<int> i { 1, 2, 3, };
  for( auto x: i )
    std::cout << x << "\n";
  for( range_trait_namespace::range_traits<std::vector<int>>::iterator_type aa = i.begin(); aa != i.end(); ++aa)
    std::cout << *aa << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I ended up using. I arrived at it myself based on a comment (it looks like this was actually a duplicate question) - but I'll mark this as answer anyway.

Comment: For me worked `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())`